# Find a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ where $a_k=2k-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have to find the simple analytical form of $S_{n}$ when $S_{n} = a_{1} + a_{2} +\cdots + a_{n}$ and $a_{k} = 2k-1$. After looking at a few terms I see that $S_{n} = 1+3+5..$. There is an arithmetic difference of 2 every time, which shows that it is an arithmetic series. Would I apply $ \dfrac{n(a_{1} + a_{n})}{2}$ , or would I go through other means to find the analytical form of the partial sum.

Comment: Do you mean to say “$S_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$”?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order to be descriptive of the content of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first idea to sum the arithmetic series works just fine. Using $a_n=2n-1$ We can rewrite this as
$$\frac{n(1 + 2n-1)}{2} = n^2$$
Alternatively, you could see the pattern with $n^2$ and then follow with a proof by induction based off the fact that
$$n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$$

Comment: Thanks i was unsure whether i was on the right trail but this clears things up.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's an arithmetic series with common difference of $2$.

Also you can calculate the sum as follows

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} 2k  - \sum_{k=1}^{n}1$$
$$                      = 2 (\sum_{k=1}^{n}k)      - n              $$

$$                     =2.\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n$$
$$                     = n^2 + n - n = n^2$$